# how to fill combobox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I am trying to fill ComboBox with the data that is come from DataBase but i am facing this error that is:

**Cannot set column 'yer'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column.**

my code is:

```
try
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(50),VSDateTiime,105),7,4) as yer FROM SessionDetails where VSNo=@VSNo group by VSDateTiime order by yer desc", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VSNo", cmbVSNo.SelectedValue);
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (rd.HasRows)
                    {
                        cmbVSYear.Items.Clear();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(rd);
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["yer"] = 0;
                        dr["yer"] = "--Select--";

                        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
                        cmbVSYear.DataSource = dt;
                        cmbVSYear.ValueMember = "yer";
                        cmbVSYear.DisplayMember = "yer";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmbVSYear.Items.Clear();
                        cmbVSYear.Items.Insert(0, "Record not found");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
```

i am working in c# .net windows form application 
Please give me solution..

Comment: check the `property` for  `MaxLength`. what number it contains?

Comment: but where i check it..? can you give me example

Comment: hm,try on the property window of your project. first click your  `cmbVSYear` on your form

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to Combobox? I suspect that the error occurred when you try to add new row on the datatable.

Comment: yes, error is occurring when i am trying to add new row on the datatable

Comment: i check the property of cmbVSYear it contain 0 Number

Comment: Have you tried given answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load `datatable` form `SqlDataReader`, it automatically assigns MaxLength to `"yer"` column which you have retrieved from database.

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(50),VSDateTiime,105),7,4)
```

Restricts `yer` column MaxLength to `4`.

You could change max length using [`DataColumn.MaxLength Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.maxlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(rd);
dt.Columns["yer"].MaxLength = 10;  //or greater
```